# Sharing WMS / XYZ / MapServer sources across multiple users / installations

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, wms, xyz

Our organisation has multiple users using QGIS and using a lot of web-based ArcGIS mapserver / WMS data.

At present we share links to WMS/WMTS, XYZ, ArcGIS Mapserver resources via  Wiki, however it would be preferable that there was a database our resource list that we could load resources from and centralise new "finds".

XYZ connections have the ability to save and load libraries to XML but WMS / ArcGIS Mapserver lists don’t seem to have this capability at a group level.

Is there any functionality or plugin that would allow this capability?

Answer (score 1):

Just create metadata for the services that can be accessed through an OGC CSW interface, for example you could use [GeoNetwork](https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/) for this.  Then users of QGIS can access the list of services using the MetaSearch tool.

[image: QGIS MetaSearch]

In this example we have a CSW catalogue of OneGeology services (and layers), and searching for all services/layers that have a minerals theme, then loading a WMS layer from the results.